# Swashbuckle 5.0.0 generated json not consistent

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle, autorest

I have an issue most likely just not understanding how swashbuckle generates swagger json file.

I have a couple API's and all of them share some infrastructure so it is packaged and therefore is shared among all of them. In that infrastructure is added swagger configurations. So I know for sure they all share the same configurations as long as the package itself is up to date.

To my surprise I find that json generated for these APIs is rather different. I use it later with autorest, 2 of those work and one fails with error: Error: Collision detected inserting into object: constructor

The obvious difference I see between those is that the one which fails has some extra parameters generated, such as:

- "Type"
- "MethodBase"
- "Exception"

I am puzzled why those are a part of that specific API swagger json even though all 3 APIs are very similar and as mentioned before all share the same swagger configurations. Am I missing something?

Package/framework versions:

- .Net Core 3.1
- Swashbuckle 5.0.0
- Swashbuckle Filters 5.0.2
- Autorest 3.0.6233

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide some code, please

Comment: @HelderSepulveda what code would you like to see? I do not really see how that is relevant as what I am really interested is how swashbuckle generates swagger json and why it is different in my 3 projects(2 are similar, one is different).

Comment: The code reproducing your issue, you should read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Issue addressed here to autorest github repo https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/3428.
Might be good to have it tracked

Comment: If the link breaks your answer will become useless. Try to summarize the links content and post the summary in you your question

Comment: Thank you but it was the issue I have created :)